# Problems with Bone Rotations within constraints

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, children

I have a 3D character rigged model with animations that I have imported into Unity 5.1.3.

The character's body parts are listed as separate game objects which you can see in the Hierarchy panel. I have assigned these body parts as children to their corresponding bones. The idea is for the user to be able to rotate the body parts within rotational constraints; the user can select a body part, rotate it to his/her requirements, and then confirm the rotation.

But what happens is that, when the user clicks on the body part the 2nd time, it most of the time automatically rotates (although within the constraints set initially). Can anyone please kindly explain why this would be happening?

Here is some code that I have added:

```
void LateUpdate(){
   if(selected_bone.name.Contains("required bone's name")){
      rotX = ClampAngle(rotX, bone_rotX_min_limit, bone_rotX_max_limit);
      rotY = ...
      rotZ = ...
   }

   Quaternion newRot = Quaternion.Euler(rotX, rotY, rotZ);
   selected_bone.localRotation = newRot;
}

float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max){
   if(angle < -360){
      angle += 360;
   }
   if(angle > 360){
      angle -= 360;
   }
   return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
}
```

Comment: Check if the condition is skipped or not

Comment: No the condition hasn't skipped.....it seems to be Unity's coordinate system; in the Inspector it shows negative angles, but in the Scene/Game it doesn't become negative (this is also confirmed when debugging and checking the euler values). For e.g., if I rotate a bone to -90 degrees, it shows this in the inspector, but on checking euler values it shows 270 degrees. So then when I select the body part again, because of the clamping condition set, it sees that 270 is greater than 90, so it sets it to 90, when it should be -90/270....